# how to enable mouse in non GUI debian in virtual box running on windows7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, debian

**background**
for a little experiment i installed the latest debian distribution .iso in my virtual box on windows7. 
I went through the installation and did not selected the desktop GUI. so i only have shell. 
My laptop uses WiFi and i could not even make a bridge so had to use NAT.

**The problem is** i need to add my ssh key to github to clone repository, is there any technique i can get that copied on clipboard ( tried xclip etc they require X GUI.etc) , 
also tried mounting the folder as the virtual box provides machanism to share a folder but i get errors ?

Looking forward to get a solution from stackExchange.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well,

- You could scp from vm to your desktop
- you could scp from desktop, to get files on vm